# Failed to connect to the remote extension host server error websocket close with status code 1006

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I am trying to connect with VScode ssh extension and am getting this error.
I have tried uninstall and reinstalling VScode. Removing .vscode folder on my local and remote machine and still the same error. Restarting my machine.

Please do you have any ideas?

Many thanks.

VS code 1.63.2
Mac 11.6.2
Remote Linux 3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64